# Losing Internet Connection Every Few Minutes on Windows 10 Home Desktop

Tags: windows-10, home-networking

I have been running Windows 10 on an older home desktop computer (Dell Inspiron 660). I've noticed the internet was dropping out (using Ethernet not Wifi) so I installed an Internet Connection Monitor that continuously checks for a dropped connection and produces a log. Sure enough, every few minutes the internet connection is lost for 10-15 seconds before coming back online. I've isolated it to this computer, as the same tool is not reporting any lost connections on other devices, and we have a good solid internet connection to the house. The Inspiron uses an integrated network card so of course I updated the drivers, which didn't help. I then purchased a new USB network card, and it still loses the connection with the USB card. I then rebooted into Safe Mode with Networking and ... the issue is resolved. No lost connection. Out of curiosity, I ran a speed test in Safe Mode that showed 400Mpbs. I then ran the same speed test in standard Windows mode and it starts fast (over 100Mbps) then immediately slows to around 30Mbps.

So for some reason, Windows 10 is losing a connection every few minutes, then resetting 10-15 seconds later. And it's throttling the bandwidth from 400Mbps to 30Mpbs.

I have spent 4-5 hours googling, researching, turning off services, resetting network settings, etc. Someone suggested running "net start > safe.txt" in safe mode, then "net start > normal.txt" in normal mode, and comparing the services running. I did this and identified 76 windows services that are running in normal mode and not in safe mode. I tried stopping all 76 services, one at a time, and doing a speed test with each one stopped. No difference - still slow, and still dropping out. There were a handful of services that I couldn't stop, though I don't have those documented. And I didn't reboot the computer after I stopped each service, so I suppose I could try that (though it would be laborious for 76 services).

I tried disabling my firewall and verified there are no antivirus programs or services running. I've run a deep virus scan with multiple virus scanning services. I removed about 40 legacy applications from my computer and restarted. No difference - still slow, still dropping every few minutes.

I tried all of [these suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpUCm.jpg), including:

- Closing the P2P update process
- Closing running background applications
- Adjusting network bandwidth settings
- Updating network drivers
- Disabling windows auto-tuning
- Disabling LSO (Large Send Offload)
- Uninstalling OneNote

I'm at my wit's end and appreciate any suggestions or ideas anyone can provide.

I can provide my hardware environment if needed, but since it works fine in Safe Mode I'm assuming it's Windows related.

I realize this is a complex issue with hundreds of variables on my desktop, but I'm hoping someone has seen this before or has some suggestions. I'm trying to avoid re-installing Windows, but I know that is always an option. SOMETHING is causing this, surely there is a way to figure it out!

Appreciate any insight, suggestions, or recommendations from this community.

Thanks!

FYI - Here's the [connection log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpUCm.jpg) showing the repeated loss of connection.

Answer (score 0):

> I then rebooted into Safe Mode with Networking and ... the issue is
> resolved. No lost connection.

Run Windows 10 Repair Install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything

There are more aggressive steps if Keep Nothing does not work.

(a) Keep just Data .
(b) Keep Nothing   (fresh install)

It is best, if Repair, Keep Everything did not work, to back up and Reinstall Windows.

You updated drivers and got a new test Network USB card, so reinstall is the main practical step left.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Trying now. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Well it's still disconnecting every few minutes, but when I ran the speed test in Safe Mode it was now slow as well (30Mbps). I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: If you did the repair install and not working, then back up and reinstall Windows.